# How to call function from one component to another component with Button

Tags: javascript, react-native

I Created a `Submit()` function in one component with name `formSignup.js` and I created another component with name `buttonSubmit.js` that contain Button(onPress) with that button I want to call `Submit()` function that is in f`ormSignup.js`.

Reason for creating separate component for Submit button is that, I wrote a lot of code for animation and also I want to re-use that Button in `loginComponent.js`.

**formSignup.js**

```
submit = () => {
...
}
```

**buttonSubmit.js**

```
How can i call submit function from  fromSignup.js here

  _onPress() {
    if (this.state.isLoading ) return;

    this.setState({isLoading: true});
    Animated.timing(this.buttonAnimated, {
      toValue: 1,
      duration: 200,
      easing: Easing.linear,
    }).start();

    setTimeout(() => {
      this._onGrow();
    }, 2000);

    setTimeout(() => {
      Actions.mainScreen();
      this.setState({isLoading: false});
      this.buttonAnimated.setValue(0);
      this.growAnimated.setValue(0);
    }, 2300);

  }
-----
return(
          <TouchableOpacity
            onPress={this._onPress}
            activeOpacity={1}>
            {this.state.isLoading ? (
              <Image source={spinner} style={styles.image} />
            ) : (
              <Text style={styles.text}>Go</Text>
            )}
          </TouchableOpacity>
);
```

Comment: are they child and parent component ? or not linked?

Comment: I just imported like import submit form './fomSingup';

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case, I have a doubt.

Are you using buttonSubmit.js component inside formSignup.js component?

if **yes**, you can achieve it by passing the **function as a props**.

```
//FormSignup.js
const FormSignup = () =>{
    const submit = () => {
        // some submit logic
    };

  //render
    return (
        <View>
            ....
            // if you are using the ButtonSubmit component in FormSignup.js, you 
            // can get function by props

            <ButtonSubmit onPressButton = {()=>submit()}/>
        </View>
    )
}


//ButtonSubmit.js
const ButtonSubmit = (props) => {
    return (
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={props.onPressButton}>
            <Text>submit</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
    )
}
```

if **No**, you should write that function as separately and import it in ButtonSubmit.js component

```
// Utility.js

const submit = () => {
    // submit logic
};

export {submit};

//================================//
//ButtonSubmit.js

import { submit } from './path/Utility.js'  // import the submit method

const ButtonSubmit = () => {
    return (
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>submit()}>
            <Text>submit</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
    )
}
```

Comment: I am using submit() function from fromSingup.js inside buttonSubmit.js

Comment: So you are using buttonSubmit inside formSubmit component, use the first method, I said. It will work perfectly. if you got cleared, upvote pls

Comment: I am using formSubmit(contain submit function) inside buttonSubmit !

Comment: @AbdulWahab <ButtomSubmit>
                              submit(){}
                              <FormSignUp/>
                       </ButtonSubmit>
correct?? if yes, you should use second method which i said

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the function as props

```
<buttonSubmit onSubmit={this.submit} />
```

And inside your buttonSubmit.js you call it from props wherever you want.

```
//inside somewhere inside buttonSubmit you call:
this.props.onSubmit();
```